# Find fullname in the same select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to get the correct full name for the column `FULLNAME_T2` based in `PERSON_T2`?

The column `FULLNAME_T2` has the wrong information. I should have the right full name based on `PERSON_T2`, and if `NULL` it should be `NULL` too. The `PERSON_T1` and `FULLNAME_T1` is ok.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/17057/2)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 
    (
     number varchar(10), 
     person varchar(20),
     dept varchar(20),
     status varchar(10)
    );

CREATE TABLE Table2 
    (
     number varchar(10), 
     person varchar(20),
     dept varchar(20),
     status varchar(10)
    );

CREATE TABLE Table3
    (
     fullname varchar(100), 
     person varchar(20),
    );


INSERT INTO Table1
(number, person, dept, status)
VALUES
('100', 'john.mayer', 'A', 'ready'),
('101', 'ana.phil', 'A', 'ready'),
('102', 'andre.muss', 'A', 'ready'),
('103', 'dani.lovato', 'A', 'ready'),
('104', 'paul.simons', 'A', 'ready'),
('105', 'carla.almeida', 'A', 'ready');

INSERT INTO Table2
(number, person, dept, status)
VALUES
('100', 'philip.ann', 'A', 'ready'),
('101', 'duna.andrea', 'A', 'ready'),
('102', 'robert.deniro', 'A', 'ready'),
('103', NULL, 'A', 'ready'),
('104', NULL, 'A', 'ready'),
('105', NULL, 'A', 'ready');

INSERT INTO Table3
(fullname, person)
VALUES
('John Antoni Mayer', 'john.mayer'),
('Ana Phil', 'ana.phil'),
('Andre Marc Muss', 'andre.muss'),
('Dani Mc Lovato', 'dani.lovato'),
('Paul Simons', 'paul.simons'),
('Carla Andrade Almeira', 'carla.almeida'),
('Philip Ann', 'philip.ann'),
('Duna Andrea', 'duna.andrea'),
('Robert Deniro', 'robert.deniro');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
    Table1.number AS Number,
    Table1.person AS Person_T1,
    Table3.fullname AS FullName_T1,
    Table2.person AS Person_T2,
    Table3.fullname AS FullName_T2
FROM
    Table1,
    Table2,
    Table3
WHERE
    Table1.number = Table2.number
AND Table1.person = Table3.person
AND Table1.dept = 'A'
AND Table1.status = 'ready'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/17057/2/0)**:

```
| NUMBER |     PERSON_T1 |           FULLNAME_T1 |     PERSON_T2 |           FULLNAME_T2 |
|--------|---------------|-----------------------|---------------|-----------------------|
|    100 |    john.mayer |     John Antoni Mayer |    philip.ann |     John Antoni Mayer |
|    101 |      ana.phil |              Ana Phil |   duna.andrea |              Ana Phil |
|    102 |    andre.muss |       Andre Marc Muss | robert.deniro |       Andre Marc Muss |
|    103 |   dani.lovato |        Dani Mc Lovato |        (null) |        Dani Mc Lovato |
|    104 |   paul.simons |           Paul Simons |        (null) |           Paul Simons |
|    105 | carla.almeida | Carla Andrade Almeira |        (null) | Carla Andrade Almeira |
```

Comment: The detail provided in this post is excellent in that it gives the full DDL, example data and a link to SQL Fiddle, however it does seem to be missing an all important ingredient.... A question?

Comment: Thanks @GarethD. The question is: The column FULLNAME_T2 has the wrong information [it should have the correct name based on PERSON_T2].

Comment: That's more of a statement!

Comment: Perhaps you could post your desired results, are you trying to `UPDATE` a field, or conditionally select one field over another?

Comment: Also, you really want to be using ANSI-standard joins, and not a bunch of WHERE statements.

Comment: A simple fix would be `Case statement`. if you want to show FULLNAME_T2 only when PERSON_T2 is not null then use `case when PERSON_T2 is not null then FULLNAME_T2 else null end`

Comment: Join from Table2 to Table3 on person to get the correct value for FULLNAME_T2. According to the data, there is miss matched person and numbers (if one looks at the data manually)

Comment: Just an idea: If table 1 holds the correct data, and table 2 holds the incorrect data, why not simply drop table 2?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, there is no incorrect data. The data in the table are correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
T1.number AS Number,
T1.person AS Person_T1,
T3.fullname AS FullName_T1,
T2.person AS Person_T2,
T3.fullname AS FullName_T2
FROM
Table1 T1 
inner join Table3 T3 on T1.Person = T3.Person
inner join Table2 T2 on T2.Person = T3.Person
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your Fiddle link, changing the query to join on `Table2` to `Table3` instead of `Table1` and making them `left outer join` instead of `join`, yields the apparent desired result. (Modified [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/17057/9/0) link)

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT Table1.number AS Number,
       Table1.person AS Person_T1,
       Table3.fullname AS FullName_T1,
       Table2.person AS Person_T2,
       Table3.fullname AS FullName_T2
  FROM Table1
         left outer join -- Change this to simple joins to make it exclusive
       Table2 on Table1.number = Table2.number
         left outer join -- Change this to simple joins to make it exclusive
       Table3 on Table2.person = Table3.person -- Difference is here
 WHERE Table1.dept = 'A'
   AND Table1.status = 'ready'
```

**Output**

```
NUMBER  PERSON_T1     FULLNAME_T1   PERSON_T2      FULLNAME_T2
100     john.mayer    Philip Ann    philip.ann     Philip Ann
101     ana.phil      Duna Andrea   duna.andrea    Duna Andrea
102     andre.muss    Robert Deniro robert.deniro  Robert Deniro
103     dani.lovato   (null)        (null)         (null)
104     paul.simons   (null)        (null)         (null)
105     carla.almeida (null)        (null)         (null)
```

More information on [Using Joins](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to select from table 3 and get the matching records from table1 or table2.

```
SELECT
  t1.number AS Number,
  t1.person AS Person_T1,
  t3.fullname AS FullName_T1,
  t2.person AS Person_T2,
  t3.fullname AS FullName_T2
FROM t3 t3
left join t1 t1 on t1.person = t3.person
left join t2 t2 on t2.person = t3.person
where t1.status = 'ready';
```

And in case you want a value either from table1 or from table2, use coalesce: `COALESCE(t1.number,t2.number) as number`.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a second reference to `Table3`, but with a different join predicate (refering to `Table2` instead of `Table1`). Since you have `NULL` values you need an `OUTER` join:

```
SELECT  t1.number AS Number,
        t1.person AS Person_T1,
        t3.fullname AS FullName_T1,
        t2.person AS Person_T2,
        t4.fullname AS FullName_T2
FROM    Table1 AS t1
        INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2
            ON t1.Number = t2.Number
        INNER JOIN Table3 AS t3
            ON t3.Person = t1.Person
        LEFT JOIN Table3 AS t4
            ON t4.Person = t2.Person
WHERE   t1.dept = 'A'
AND     t1.status = 'ready';
```

This gives:

```
| NUMBER |     PERSON_T1 |           FULLNAME_T1 |     PERSON_T2 |           FULLNAME_T2 |
|--------|---------------|-----------------------|---------------|-----------------------|
|    100 |    john.mayer |     John Antoni Mayer |    philip.ann |            Philip Ann |
|    101 |      ana.phil |              Ana Phil |   duna.andrea |           Duna Andrea |
|    102 |    andre.muss |       Andre Marc Muss | robert.deniro |         Robert Deniro |
|    103 |   dani.lovato |        Dani Mc Lovato |        (null) |                (null) |
|    104 |   paul.simons |           Paul Simons |        (null) |                (null) |
|    105 | carla.almeida | Carla Andrade Almeira |        (null) |                (null) |
```

N.B. I have switched your joins from ANSI-89 join syntax, to the newer ANSI-92 join syntax. There are a number of compelling reasons to switch, Aaron Bertrand has written a [great article listing them](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).